# ERROR 403 - Forbidden! phpMyAdmin ISPConfig

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ispconfig

On our webserver we have have ISPconfig setup to manage multiple sites and databases that we develop. Recently, however we have had the need to upgrade php from 5.3 to 7 which worked out OK. I am however now having a problem accessing phpMyAdmin.

I have checked the usual things-

1.) Permissions on the phpmyadmin directory (Located at /etc/phpmyadmin)

2.) Checked the permissions from within the apache.conf file located in the phpmyadmin folder and ensured that apache has a link to the file. For testing purposes I Changed anything with Deny and to Allow from all - Here is the apache file:

```
    # phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all

    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
        php_admin_value memory_limit 2G
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 200M
        php_admin_value post_max_size 200M
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

**Update** Checking apache error logs provided this clue: 
    [Tue Sep 26 09:34:55.975433 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 15910] [client 192.168.9.80:63078] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin

The error received is a Permissions issue i beleive, just not sure whats causing it.

In ISPConfig when i click the link to the right of a database that should take me to phpmyadmin: https://webdev:8080/phpmyadmin

I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Updated the original post for you, thanks for responding!